# ngx-bootstrap datePicker bsValueChange not firing

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap version 5.6.2

Docs here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/5.6.2/#/datepicker#value-change-event

For some reason, the `bsValueChange` event is not firing when I use `datesDisabled`. So this is working:

```
<bs-datepicker-inline
              [bsValue]="bsInlineValue"
              [bsConfig]="dateSelectConfig"
              (bsValueChange)="onDayChange($event)"
              ></bs-datepicker-inline>
```

But if I do this:

```
<bs-datepicker-inline
              [bsValue]="bsInlineValue"
              [bsConfig]="dateSelectConfig"
              [datesDisabled]="disabledDates"
              (bsValueChange)="onDayChange($event)"
              ></bs-datepicker-inline>
```

the `bsValueChange` event stops firing.

`datesDisabled` is working correctly but I should mention (as an aside to this question) that I **cannot** use `datesEnabled` as per the docs as it gives me the error "*Can't bind to 'datesEnabled' since it isn't a known property of 'bs-datepicker-inline'.*"

Please help as I really need to use `(bsValueChange)` with either `datesDisabled` or ideally `datesEnabled`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The **bsValueChange** event wont get fired if your component is in disabled state. Setting **datesDisabled** to false will get your event firing again. Change the binded value of **datesDisabled** property either toggling it true/false as per your need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't follow. datesDisabled is a date array. It is initialised empty and then I push a load of dates in via an onInit method to calculate which dates should be disabled. Are you saying it needs to be initialised with false rather than an empty array?